# Strings display problems after converting java source files to utf-8 and setting eclipse to utf-8

Tags: java, string, eclipse, utf-8

In order to adapt to new testing tools, I had to convert all my java source files to utf-8 (mostly from windows1252 or iso-8859-1) and changed Eclipse configuration to use utf-8 by default. But the conversion resulted in problems on some strings containing accents.

These strings are read from a database (NLS_CHARACTERSET : WE8MSWIN1252) then sent to a Delphi program using a socket. Neither the database nor the delphi program have been modified.

The strings are retrieved from the database using :

```
ArrayList<String> menus = new ArrayList<String>(); 
String query = "SELECT ITEM FROM menus ...";
psmt = con.prepareStatement( query );
rs = psmt.executeQuery();
while( rs.next() ) {
    if( rs.getString( "ITEM" ) == null ) continue;
    String s = rs.getString( "ITEM" );
    menus.add( s );
}
return menus;
```

Then they are sent to the other program using a socket and printwriter

```
Socket socket = new Socket( getTcpIPAddress(), getTcpCommandPort() );
PrintWriter pred = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

String str = "ADD:";
str = str.concat( menus.get( 0 ) );
pred.println(str);
```

I've tried a number of different conversions to create string to send but I still get strange characters instead of accents

```
String s = rs.getString( "ITEM" );
String m1 = new String( s.getBytes("UTF-8") );
String m2 = new String( s.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1" );
String m3 = new String( s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") );
String m4 = new String( s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8" );
String m5 = new String( s.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1" );
String m6 = new String( s.getBytes(), "UTF-8" );

byte[] ba = rs.getBytes( "ITEM" );
String b1 = new String( ba ); 
String b2 = new String( ba, "ISO-8859-1" ); 
String b3 = new String( ba, "UTF-8" ); 
String b4 = new String( ba, "windows-1252" ); 
String b5 = new String( ba, "US-ASCII" );
```

Any idea how to get my accents back, apart from converting the source files back and resetting the default configuration for Eclipse?

Comment: It looks to me that once you've executed this: `String s = rs.getString( "ITEM" );` it is too late.   If getString() returns a Java String, it must have **already** converted what it  got from the database into UTF-16, since by definition a Java String contains only UTF-16.  You need some variant of getString() that understands the character set used by the data and can convert that to UTF-16.

Comment: I'd try `String s = new String(rs.getBytes("ITEM"), "ISO-8859-1")`

Comment: Thanks for the help but it's already one of the test I've tried :   byte[] ba = rs.getBytes( "ITEM" ); String b2 = new String( ba, "ISO-8859-1" );  Unfortunately, it still gives me strange chars

Comment: Oh, I did not notice that.  Sorry.

Comment: `new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())` is the most likely culprit.  You are relying on the system’s default charset.  The receiving end may or may not use the same charset.  Don’t try to mangle or ‘fix’ the String with getBytes/constructor round trips.  Just establish a consistent charset for your connection on both ends.  (UTF-8 is almost always the best choice.)

Comment: Do you know of a way to set the charset for the outputstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the Eclipse configuration although I don't understand why.

Setting the options back to default (Cp1252) in Window -> Preferences, General -> Workspace -> "Text file encoding" fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding always comes into play when converting between bits and characters and back. The `#getBytes()` call itself is converting the characters in the string into bits according to your platform's runtime default charset. There are versions of `#getBytes()` that take character set information to help avoid that. You should specify a charset there, as well as when you instantiate the `OutputStreamWriter`, to avoid these unintended changes.

Comment: Are you sure about the conversion in the getBytes() function? There shouldn't be any when you deal with bytes, otherwise any binary data would end up corrupted.

Comment: Only if you were to convert that binary data into characters, or vice versa.  Check the implementation of `#getBytes()` if you're skeptical.